# Custom li styling next to a floating item

Tags: html, css

I have custom styled list items that can go over one line and need to stay aligned. In the below snippet the first list works fine.

But the second snippet items go to the left of the image due to the absolute positioning. Is there any way I can position the items adjacent to the floating element so they don't go over it?

The content is coming from ckeditor so all i know is that they can enter a floating left figure and can surround it with anything at all

```css
.figure.figure-left {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
}

ul:not(.cke_panel_list) {
    list-style: none!important;
    padding-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
    /* clear: both; */
}

ul:not(.cke_panel_list) li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f10c'!important;
    color: #009EE0;
    font-size: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.figure {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.figure img.img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<h3>Good list. Atta boy</h3>
  <ul class="arrow-list">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc fdfdsfsafsafdsa dsf ds fdsf ds fds fds fs</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="figure figure-left"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive" width=200 src="https://cdn.sparesinmotion.com/sites/default/files/test-product-test.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Bad list, bold!</h3>
  <ul class="arrow-list">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
<h3>And some more stuff, who knows what the editors might add?</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just position it relatively? `position: relative;
    left: -1.1rem;`

Comment: `.figure.figure-left + h3 { clear: both; }`

Comment: @epascarello then I lose alignment.

Comment: @demkovych I want it to be to the right of the image and also don't know what the content will be

Comment: @rory, seemed fine when I made the change

Comment: The `position:relative` also probably needs a negative margin left or right on the marker to stop it taking up space on the line.

Comment: `ul.arrow-list {overflow: auto;}`

Comment: @epascarello it pushes the list items to the left

Comment: @demkovych please add as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily clear your floats just with `overflow: auto` on the list:

```css
.figure.figure-left {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
}

ul:not(.cke_panel_list) {
    list-style: none!important;
    padding-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
    /* clear: both; */
}

ul.arrow-list {overflow: auto;}

ul:not(.cke_panel_list) li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: '\f10c'!important;
    color: #009EE0;
    font-size: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.figure {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.figure img.img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<h3>Good list. Atta boy</h3>
  <ul class="arrow-list">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc fdfdsfsafsafdsa dsf ds fdsf ds fds fds fs</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="figure figure-left"><img alt="" class="img img-responsive" width=200 src="https://cdn.sparesinmotion.com/sites/default/files/test-product-test.png">
  </div>
  <h3>Bad list, bold!</h3>
  <ul class="arrow-list">
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc List Item going over one line and wraps around and stays nicely aligned etc etc etc</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
<h3>And some more stuff, who knows what the editors might add?</h3>
</div>
```